# Ajax call returns nothing

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to make an ajax call on click on anchor tag dynmically generated from $.each loop for a JSON response.

For Information : #records is my table and .update is the class of anchor tag in that table.

Please be informed that the table is generated dynamically.
Now the problem is that my ajax call is returning nothing even i have checked it error: but no response received. I have tried alerting my var data just before the ajax call and it worked.So the problem starts from the ajax call. Moreover, my server side code is running fine.

```
// Update existing customers 
            $("#records").on('click', ".update", function() {
                        var data = '?'+ $(this).attr('id');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "viewcustomers.php",
                            data: data,
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            }
                        });
                        });
```

Thanks in advance.

For reference below is the code that generates the table.

```
 // Function to make datagrid
            function getRecords() {
                $.getJSON("viewcustomers.php", function(data) {
                    var items = [];
                    var xTd = '';
                    var xTr = '';
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        var c = 0;
                        var id = 0;
                        $.each(val, function(key1, val1) {
                            if (c == 0)
                            {
                                id = val1;
                            }
                            c++;
                            xTd += '<td>' + val1 + '</td>';
                        });
                        xTd += '<td><a href="#" id="update=' + id + '" class="update">Edit</a></td>';
                        xTd += '<td><a href="customers.php?delete=' + id + '">Delete</a></td>';
                        xTr = '<tr>' + xTd + '</tr>';
                        items.push(xTr);
                        xTd = '';
                        xTr = '';
                    });
                    $("#records").append(items);
                });
            }
```

Updated the server side code:
page url : localhost/hotel/viewcustomers.php

/**
 * Fetch single row for the purpose of update / delete.
 */

```
if(isset($_GET['update'])){
    $customer = new Customers;
    $Id = $_GET['update'];
    $customer_single = $customer->View_Single_Customer($Id);
    echo json_encode($customer_single);
    unset($customer);

}
```

Comment: Try this `data:"id="+$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: If it's executing but returning nothing your problem is with the server-side code. What happens if you copy-paste the URL you saw in the network tab in the address bar?

Comment: when i manually enter the url in serverside page it shows me the result

Comment: The code that generates the table is irrelevant... you need to show us the URL and the server response.

Comment: @Raheel can you show us what that URL looks like? Also, the PHP code that returns the data?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum check the updated part. Just to let you know that Naveen solution worked but i want to send it via data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is not used the right way `var data = '?'+ $(this).attr('id');`

Change it like this: `var my_id = $(this).attr('id');`

Then update the line `data: data` with `data : {id:my_id}`

**Complete code :**

```
$("#records").on('click', ".update", function() {
    var my_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "viewcustomers.php",
        data : {id : my_id},
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

**Or do it like this:**

```
$("#records").on('click', ".update", function() {
    var param = '?id='+ $(this).attr('id'); /*notice that I have added "id=" */
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "viewcustomers.php" + param,
        /* remove the data attribute */
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: so i concatenate '?' because my server side code starts with if(isset($GET['update']){..}

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update=4' at line 1

Comment: thanks i edited my url and its working... but it will be a favor if you can tell me what was causing my code to stop running ?

Comment: @Raheel second one is looks like mine :(

Comment: @Naveen yes naveen i commented above that your code worked fine ... :) but i accepted his first answer because of same approach ..anyways i voted your answer too ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Modify it as

```
$("#records").on('click', ".update", function() {
  var request = '?id='+ $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "viewcustomers.php" + request,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: -1 , sorry, but OP just said ([the problem is not with the URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920485/ajax-call-returns-nothing/20920506#comment31409161_20920485) and data)

Comment: Although that worked perfect but i didn't understand the actualprolem

Comment: Then why did you say it worked when you used the same URL from the network tab? -_-

Comment: actually i get the response by Naveen's method but he omitted data: part my goal is not just to deliver but also to learn what i am doing wrong :)